# Async.eachSeries only affects first array item

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to delete every item in an array (in this case product records). However, only one item is deleted. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
app.post('/products/deletemulti', function (req, res, next) {
  // Async function: Find all categories
  var products = [1,2]; // Num products created
  console.log(products);
  // Update all products
  async.eachSeries(products, function (product, next) {
    console.log(product);
    if (ObjectId.isValid(product)) {
      Product.count({'_id': product}, function(error, count) {
        if (count != 0) {
          Product.remove({'_id': product}, function (error, product) {
            if (error) return next(error);
            else return next();
          });
        }
      });
    }
    else return next();
  });
  res.send("Delete products.");
});
```

Comment: Did you try printing the `count` through every iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

async.eachSeries takes three arguments. The input array, the iterator function, and the final callback. You're calling the `res.send` too soon, probably causing the iterator to not execute.

I've cleaned up this code a little and added an er check on the response.

```
app.post("/products/deletemulti", function(req, res, next) {
  // Async function: Find all categories
  var products = [1, 2]; // Num products created
  console.log(products);
  // Update all products

  async.eachSeries(
    products.filter(ObjectId.isValid),
    function(product, next) {
      Product.count({ _id: product }, function(error, count) {
        if (count != 0) {
          Product.remove({ _id: product }, next);
        }
      });
    },
    function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).send("Did not delete products");
      } else {
        res.send("Delete products.");
      }
    }
  );
});
```